# java - volatile keyword also for non-primitives

Tags: java, volatile

I am unsure if the volatile keyword should also be used for non-primitives. I have a class member which is set/assigned by one thread, and accessed by another thread. Should I declare this member volatile?

```
private /* volatile */ Object o;

public void setMember(Object o) {
    this.o = o;
}

public Object getMember() {
    return o;
}
```

Here, setMember(...) is called by one thread and getMember() is called by another one.

If it was a boolean, for example, the answer would be yes.

I am using Java 1.4 and the member in this case is read-only. So I am only caring about visibility in this case, hence my question about the volatile keyword.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes - `volatile` has exactly the same significance for reference-type fields that it has for primitive-type fields. Except that in the case of reference types, the members of the object the field refers to must *also* be designed for multi-threaded access.

Comment: Just curious about this statement -   the members of the object the field refers to must also be designed for multi-threaded access  - would be great if you could expand as to why it is so ?

Comment: @jtkSource: volatile affects only the field, but the field only contains a reference. So volatile ensures that other threads see updates to that reference, but if the referred-to object doesn't use volatile or synchronization properly, then other threads could fail to see updates of that object's fields.

Comment: just thinking out - so if a volatile variable refer to a object, wouldn't the non-volatile variables be also made 'visibile' in a consistent way within the context of the object that declared it volatile? If there are other objects that also refer to this 'referred to object' in a non-volatile way, would only those objects be in risk of not seeing the variable in a consistent state ? would there be a chance that there are two representations of the same object in memory ? - Let me know if I have confused my logic.

Comment: @jtkSource No, no, and yes (the two representations would exist in the caches for different CPU cores). volatile has an effec *only* on one variably, which would be the reference itself. It has no effect whatsoever on the object the reference points at.

Answer (score 8):

You can, and it may be helpful, but remember the keyword just applies to the setting of the reference.  It has no effect on multi-thread visibility of the properties inside that object.  If it is stateful, you probably want to synchronize around each access to it anyway, to ensure the desired happens-before relationships.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, your code is correct. In this case the reference itself is volatile, so chances to the reference are automatically visible in all other threads, but not changes to the object being referenced.

Answer (score 1):

If we look up `AtomicInteger` class, it has declared `value` as **`volatile`** , So it can be used in multi-threaded environment without any thread cache issue.

```
public class AtomicInteger {
    private volatile int value;

    /**
     * Gets the current value.
     *
     * @return the current value
     */
    public final int get() {
        return value;
    }

    /**
     * Sets to the given value.
     *
     * @param newValue the new value
     */
    public final void set(int newValue) {
        value = newValue;
    }

}
```

But if you think reference to AtomicInteger it shelf will be modified with different AtomicInteger objects by many threads; then you need volatile for that reference too.

```
private volatile AtomicInteger reference = new AtomicInteger(0);
```

Mostly it won't be the case; only value of the object will changed; hence declare it as final.

```
private final AtomicInteger reference = new AtomicInteger(0);
```